# SQL Server, fetching data from multiple joined tables. Why is slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with performance when retrieving data from SQL Server.

My sql query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
  table_1.id, 
  table_1.value, 
  table_2.id, 
  table_2.value,..., 
  table_20.id, 
  table_20.value
From table_1 
INNER JOIN table_2 
ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id 
INNER JOIN table_3 
ON  table_2.id = table_3.table_2_id...
WHERE table_1.row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

So, I am fetching 20 results. 
This query takes about 5 seconds to execute.
When I select only table_1.id, it returns results instantly.
Because of that, I guess that problem is not in JOINs, it is in retrieving data from multiple tables.

Any suggestions how I would speed up this query?

Comment: In management studio run the query with Actual Execution plan switched on. Take a look at the diagram for the query - which has the highest % of the query or which has the fattest line in the query. If that doesn't help you solve it yourself by pointing to an index or other issue then please post the image into your question.

Comment: I included actual execution plan in query execution and found out that the slowest thing is Clustered Index Seek on several tables. Do I have solution for my problem except reducing number of columns returned by the query?

Comment: Hi all.
Thank you for your answers.
I included actual execution plan in query execution and found out that the slowest thing is Clustered Index Seek on several tables.
Do I have solution for my problem except reducing number of columns returned by the query?

Comment: Yes. Get better hardware. A LOT of people dont really unerstand how much memory and discs a larger database server needs. Normal discs, small servers are notoriously simlpy crap for executing complex qjueries because there is no way to do it efficiently. Like trying to win formula one in a fiat panda - just wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables are designed properly (have a useful primary key etc.), then the first thing I would check is this:

- are there indices on each of the foreign key columns in the child tables?

SQL Server does not automatically create indices on the foreign key columns - yet those are indeed very helpful for speeding up your JOINs.

Other than that: just look at the query plans! They should tell you everything about this query - what indices are being used (or not), what operations are being executed to get the results....

Without knowing a lot more about your tables, their structure and the data they contain (how much? What kind of values? etc.), there's really not much we can do to help here....

Answer (score 0):

Between can really slow a query, what do you want to achieve with it

also

- Do you have an on the columns you are joining on
- You could use with(nolock) on the table
- Check to execution plan to see whats taking so long

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
SELECT     
     table_1.id,     
     table_1.value,     
     table_2.id,     
     table_2.value,...,     
     table_20.id,     
     table_20.value     
FROM 
     table_1     
     INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id AND table_1.row_Number between 1 and 20
     INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_2.id = table_3.id
```

I mean before joining to another table, you choose range of data.